# Delete all Null values from a table without specifying columns name manually

Tags: sql, sql-server, information-schema

I want to delete all the null from table but let suppose i have 200 - 500 coumns so its seems logical to delete them in a dynamic way

i was trying to it something like this while using Information_Schema.Coulmns

```
delete from tableName
where INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS is null
```

but as the INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS can only be use after 'from' im confused how can i do that

Comment: You mean you want to delete all columns from a specific table, where all values are null? Your question is not particularly clear.

Comment: Do you mean you want update the Null values to empty string?

Comment: @AhmedSaeed correct i want to make them blank or delete the values no the column as mentioned by FAB

Comment: `delete from tablename where yourcolumn is null`, but that deletes the entire row, not just where your colum is null. Making the records blank is not the same as deleting the record or  deleting your column. Of course you can use the information schema to create dynamic SQL to do this, but I recommend reading more on very basic SQL syntax (like the `DELETE` statement) before attempting to use dynamic SQL. In case is not clear, you can't just delete the `NULL` value...

Comment: NULL has a purpose, don't be afraid of NULL. Replacing NULL with an actual phony value (empty string, or 0) is a really bad idea - it can cause you lots of trouble in the future.

Comment: its not just about null in specific, yes i know null is better than 0 or '' but as I said null is just an e.g. ,  i can do this for any other data type in the future when needed

Comment: Do you mean you want UPDATE, not DELETE? I.e. for each column in a table, UPDATE all instances of a specific value to another value?

Comment: yes correct , im sorry for phrasing it with delete

Answer (score 1):

Please try something like this (not tested).

```
  declare @table_name sysname = 'tableName';
  declare @sql varchar(max)
        
  select 
        @sql = coalesce(@sql + ', ', 'UPDATE ' +@table_name+' SET '+char(13))
        +[name] + '= coalesce('+[name]+', '''')' + char(13)
    from sys.columns 
  where object_id = object_id(@table_name)
  print @sql
  exec(@sql)
```

Comment: @FAB since you may have multiple columns, it is not correct to include them in the where, but rather, better to check for each column inside the SET phrase.

Comment: My bad, I've misread your statement. You're updating all columns...

Answer (score 1):

```
declare @col varchar(255), @cmd varchar(max)
DECLARE getinfo cursor for
SELECT c.name FROM sys.tables t JOIN sys.columns c ON t.Object_ID = c.Object_ID
WHERE t.Name = 'CUSTOMERS'

OPEN getinfo

FETCH NEXT FROM getinfo into @col

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    SELECT @cmd = 'Delete FROM CUSTOMERS WHERE ' + QUOTENAME(@col) + ' IS NULL'
    exec(@cmd)

    FETCH NEXT FROM getinfo into @col
END

CLOSE getinfo
DEALLOCATE getinfo
```

@sagar you want to delete row which column having null value you can find delete that rows this way and here customers is demo table name

Answer (score 0):

Okay i got a solution

this query is replacing each cell value to '' which is null

```
DECLARE @table_name NVARCHAR(100) = 'SqlInsertST2'
DECLARE @column_name NVARCHAR(100), @query NVARCHAR(MAX)

DECLARE column_cursor CURSOR FOR 
SELECT COLUMN_NAME
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME = @table_name

OPEN column_cursor

FETCH NEXT FROM column_cursor INTO @column_name

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    SET @query = 'UPDATE ' + @table_name + ' SET ' + QUOTENAME(@column_name) + ' = '''' WHERE ' + QUOTENAME(@column_name) + ' IS NULL'
    EXEC (@query)
    FETCH NEXT FROM column_cursor INTO @column_name
END

CLOSE column_cursor
DEALLOCATE column_cursor
```

Comment: do take note that you are setting the value to `''` regardless of the data type of the column. Not all data type is able to convert from `''` implicitly.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).